# How to Use GetIntExtra (Intent) in a canvas in Android/Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, android-canvas

When I pass a var in an Intent between activities I use the PutExtra/GetExtra like this:

SecondActivity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("score", 2);
                StartActivity(intent);
```

MainActivity:

```
int score = Intent.GetIntExtra("score", 0);
```

The problem is when i'm trying to use the GetIntExtra within a Canvas, it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!

I tried to pass a var with Intent to a Canvas Activity and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is when i'm trying to use the GetIntExtra within a Canvas, it doesn't work. I tried to pass a var with Intent to a Canvas Activity and it didn't work.

Do you mean using Intent(.GetIntExtra) in Canvas(`onDraw()`)? It just draws, not handles activity flow.

For more info about Intent, you can refer to the official documentation: [Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters).